# Enable or disable toggle option for FCM push notification for web

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web

I have completed Firebase cloud Messaging  push notification on web based but i need to control the notification on web through toggle based like enable or disable.

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.requestPermission()
.then(function() {
console.log('Notification permission granted.');
return messaging.getToken(); 
});
```

Comment: share the code you have written. @Gayathri Manohar

Comment: Thanks for your response. please see the above code what i did on script.I received the notification but i want to add enable and disable button on my webiste, default chrome will control. we have to control the chrome by our toggle button

Answer (score 0):

I think ,the fcm doesn't give the option to disable the push notifications, you can try a workaround, as you are using service worker for the push notifications,and you want to enable and disable the push notifications whenever you want, there is the option of **unregister on the service worker** , i believe when we unregister the service worker i.e the service worker is disabled , the push notifications will also no longer appear

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(
    function(registrations) {
        for(let registration of registrations) {
            registration.unregister();
        }
});
```